# MS Access Refresh and Requery won't work in Form with Combo Box to select records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms

I have a form ("MAIN") that uses an unbound Combo Box with a query row source to allow users to select a record from a table ("SPONSORS") to edit in the form.  (Technically, the editing is in a subform ("SPONSORSHIPS") as each record in "SPONSORS" can have multiple related records in "SPONSORSHIPS".)

There is also a "New Record" button on the form "MAIN" to open a separate form ("NEW") and create a new record in the "SPONSORS" table.

The problem is that when they return to original form ("MAIN"), they are not able to select the newly created record using the Combo Box.  I've tried both Refresh and Re-query with VBA and macros without success.

The two things I've found that do work are, 1) click the "Refresh All" button in the Access menu, or 2) close and reopen the form ("MAIN").  Neither are intuitive or efficient solutions for my end users.  I would really like the form to simply refresh/re-query so that the new record is available immediately.

Comment: When was the requery triggered? Requery should work, as long as it is called after the new record has been committed to your table.

Comment: Does your code specifically Requery the combobox?

Comment: I've tried it in a couple different event procedure positions... "on got focus" for the Form and "on got focus" and "on click" for the Combo Box - for both the Combo Box and the whole Form.  I've checked the table and the new record is there, and I've even gotten to the point where it will show up in the query for the combo box, but you can't actually select the record in the form.

Comment: It would be useful to see the button-code that opens the 'add new' form; the code (if any) that adds the new record; and wherever the code is that's trying to requery the combobox.

Comment: I’ll be back at on Monday and post some code samples. Thanks for the feedback so far everyone.

Comment: Is your "NEW" form being presented as a modal dialog? It sounds like you have a timing problem where your requerying and refreshing is happening before the new record is committed from the "NEW" form.

Comment: I think it is indeed a timing problem of some sort.  I’ve tried the NEW form as regular and modal.  No difference.  I thought I had it fixed when I simply added Forms![MAIN].Requery on the Click event of the Close button of the NEW form.  It actually worked… and then after a few new records it stopped working.  That makes no sense!

Comment: Well, I'm not satisfied, but I went with a workaround.  I added a button to the MAIN form that triggers Me.Requerry.  Basically the same as the ribbon "Refresh All" button, but having it on the form makes it a little more intuitive for the end user.  Would still love to figure out the right way to code it to happen automatically when the NEW form closes.